# How do I use a yuv420 image as a texture in webgl?

Tags: javascript, image, webgl

I have an Uint8Array that stores a yuv420 image. I need to draw to a canvas using webgl but I also need the yuv to rgb conversion to happen in the shader as it needs to be performant.

I have found other solutions, but they require three different textures, one for y, u and v and that means I would need to split the image beforehand which I don't think would be performant.

So far I have it almost working but I think the colour data is missing and the image is repeated with strange lines:

```
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl2")

fetch("input.yuv")
.then(async (image)=>{




const vertexShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
in vec4 aPosition;
in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 vTexCoord;
void main()
{
    vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
    gl_Position = aPosition;
}`;

const fragmentShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
#pragma vscode_glsllint_stage: frag

precision mediump float;

in vec2 vTexCoord;


uniform sampler2D uSampler;

out vec4 fragColor;


void main()
{
    fragColor = texture(uSampler,vTexCoord);
}`;


const program = gl.createProgram();

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);

gl.linkProgram(program);

if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
}

gl.useProgram(program);

const vertexBufferData = new Float32Array([
    -.9,.9,
    -.9,-.9,
    .9,.9,
    .9,-.9,
]);

const texCoordBufferData = new Float32Array([
    0,1,
    0,0,
    1,1,
    1,0,
]);

const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);

const texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBufferData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0,0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);


gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uSampler'), 0);

let texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

let imageData = await image.arrayBuffer()
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 640,480, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(imageData));

gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
})
```

[image: what the canvas shows]

This is the image on the canvas which appears to be the image repeated and then in black and white.

I assume that's because I'm sending it as RGBA but I'm not sure how to do it properly. I assume the reason for the image being repeated is just because I have TEXTURE_WRAP_S? But I'm not exxaclty sure.

Comment: There's no built in support for YUV image formats, you'll have to transform it to RGB in the shader code yourself, search for "yuv420 to rgb".